# neo4j cannot connect to local server via browser

Tags: neo4j

After starting my local neo4j server on my Win 10 machine:

[image: local neo4j server already started]

and navigating to the Browser, I attempted to log in. But the "Connecting..." message never goes away:

[image: always show "connecting"]

How do I fix this?

Comment: My browser is chrome  63.0.3239.132 64bit .
I use  Microsoft Edge instead , it works .

Comment: Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, your question in current format is not having enough information to help...